# How to disconnect Serial session while keeping tab open in MobaXTerm

Tags: mobaxterm

If I use something like ExtraPutty, I can press hangup, and the session is terminated, but the data does not leave the screen.

How can I do something like this in MobaXTerm?

I've tried right clicking on the tab, and all I see is "close tab", there's no "disconnect".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A serial session has no real notion of a disconnect.
You just stop sending/receiving data.
(A serial device can normally not distinguish between "cable disconnected" and "I'm receiving no more data".)

Some devices (on the other end of the connection) can have a "end of session" like behavior but that depends on the device.
E.g. Some devices will interpret a serial-line "break" as a terminator. (You can send a break from MobaXTerm using the "special command" menu.)

If you still need to refer to the output of the serial session later you can always save the MobaXTerm terminal buffer to a file or print it.

Comment: Thank you, Tonny. I realize there is no actual disconnect, but these programs do lay claim to the COM-port, which is what I want to release, without removing the data from the screen. I can do that in other terminal programs, but I do like MobaXTerm, so I was hoping it was possible. I want to swap between using MobaXTerm and LabVIEW, both using that same COM-port. Saving the terminal buffer doesn't fit my use exactly, I just want to swap freely between them, without extra clicking around.

Comment: @DrOnline I get it. MobaXTerm is my favorite terminal program as well. But I don't think there is anything you can do about it.

Answer (score 1):

I use a USB-to-RS232 connector.  if the USB gets disconnected, the session gets disconnected, but the tab remains open.  Once the serial port is available again, it is possible to reconnect the session, from within the tab.
You need a soft way to get to this state, maybe disabling the serial port through the device manager or similar.